# Rsync: Only backup non-hidden files and whitelisted hidden files?

Tags: command-line, rsync, backup

I use `rsync` to backup my entire home folder, which includes configuration files for my software and desktop environment. When distro-hopping I don't want to save these configuration files, save for a few such as my browser or email client.

Configuration files in the home folder are always hidden or in hidden directories, so my solution is to have `rsync` backup all non-hidden files, and only backup hidden files contained in a whitelist, excluding all other hidden files.

**How can I accomplish this with a single `rsync` command?**

Answer (score 1):

Create a file with hidden files/dirs if you need to backup

**Example:**

```
vim includeFile.list

.xpto.conf
.my.cfg
```

And execute rsync

```
rsync -avz --include-from=includeFile.list --exclude=".*" source/ destination/
```