# How to copy a remote tree without hidden files?

Tags: scp, file-copy

I have a tree with 100GB of data, and I'd like to `scp` it to a remote machine. A large portion of the data is in hidden `.files` that I'd like to keep locally, but I don't need it remotely.

Is it possible to copy over via `scp` or another method the entire tree without the hidden files?

Comment: can you share what you have tried ? the full command that you are using to make a copy for example

Comment: i recommend this asnwer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1228535/6147182

Comment: Also see [Rsync: Only backup non-hidden files and whitelisted hidden files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/384313/100397)

Comment: Thanks for the comments; I used the `--exclude` flag suggested.